# Xcode Server won't build because source control information is in an invalid format

Tags: xcode, git, continuous-integration, xcode-server

I have XCode Server set up with XCode 6.4 and OSX Server 4.1.5. I had integrations running fine until I transferred my git repository to another bitbucket account. No big deal right? Wrong for me :(. After I transferred my repository, I changed my git remote, I changed the repository location in Preferences in Xcode on my dev computer as well as on my server. Regular git functions are working fine from the command line and from within XCode. Nothing seems wrong until I try to run an integration and then it gives me the following build service error:

```
Could not check out sources because the source control information is in an invalid format.
```

I tried deleting my bot and creating another one. I tried cloning my project straight from the new location into another folder in case something had gotten out of sync. I git reset hard to the remote branch just in case even though there was nothing different. I tried cleaning and restarting everything multiple times. I reset XCode Server too (sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset) and am still getting the error making me think I really did somehow mess up my git repository as far as XCode is concerned, but I have no ideas about what XCode doesn't like about my source control information. Does anyone have any ideas for what I can do or try? I've been tearing my hair out for hours.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.